# Format a string later?

Tags: python, string-formatting

If I have a list of strings, some of which contain codes contained within `{}`, is it possible to  use `format()` on those strings at a later time?

In the case I have I want to write some flavor text for bodily damage such as `"He appears to be limping on his {1} leg."` but I would like to format that string with either 'left' or 'right' depending on the leg in question.

Comment: I am sure that trying and figuring it out yourself would take you less that writing to SE :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure it is possible. Just store the strings and call `.format()` on them later:

```
>>> someformat = 'Hello {}!'
>>> someformat
'Hello {}!'
>>> print someformat.format('World')
Hello World!
```

`.format()` is just a method on a string, only when you call that method will the string be interpreted as a template. Just like `.strip()` and `.join()`, you can call that method on any string object at a time of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `.format()` whenever you need it.

You define the format string at the very top of the file and can even use it several times with several different data.

When you really call it is completely up to you (resp. your needs), as long as you have it referenced somewhere.

I.e., don't do

```
TEMPLATE = "He appears to be limping on his {0} leg."
[...]
TEMPLATE = TEMPLATE.format('left')
```

as you'll lose your original template.

Instead, do

```
TEMPLATE = "He appears to be limping on his {0} leg."
[...]
leftsentence = TEMPLATE.format('left')
[...]
rightsentence = TEMPLATE.format('right')
[...]
middlesentence = TEMPLATE.format('middle')
```

where and whenever you need.

Comment: `'middle leg'`? `o.O`

Comment: :-} tried to be funny...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `{0}` to match the first argument passed to `format`.

Example:

```
>>> s = "He appears to be limping on his {0} leg"
>>> s.format("bad")
'He appears to be limping on his bad leg'
```

Comment: You can use `{1}` just fine:  `s = 'He appears to be linking on his {1} leg'; print s.format(None, 'bad')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, with a kludge :)

Comment: The point is that there is nothing forcing you using all parameters passed into the `.format()` method, your answer is a little too sparse on detail on that.